# Game views won't change

Tags: python, model-view-controller, pygame

I'm using the MVC arquitecture for a game in pygame however when I try to do the transition from the menu view (starter view) to the game view the screen will keep displaying the menu view instead of changing.

Here are the views classes:

```
pygame.init()

class MainDisplay:
    # Handles current view and all it's events and acts as broker between views
    def __init__(self, view):
        self.current_view = view

    def draw(self):
        self.current_view.drawAll()

    def functions(self):
        self.current_view.functions()

class MenuDisplay:
    # Menu View
    def __init__(self):
        self.button = pygame.image.load("src/trans-button.png")
        self.button = pygame.transform.scale(self.button, (display_width - 84, 70))
        self.start_button = self.button
        self.tutorial_button = self.button
        self.top10_button = self.button
        self.salir_button = self.button
        self.initial_pos = 220
        self.event_i = self.event_g = self.event_t = self.event_e = False
        self.text_color = (255,255,0)

    def checkSelection(self, posX, startPosY, endPosY):
        # We get the mouse coordinates
        self.mouse_x, self.mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        # Then proceed to evaluate it position in relation with the buttons
        if(self.mouse_x >= posX and self.mouse_x <= self.button.get_width() + posX and self.mouse_y >= startPosY and self.mouse_y <= endPosY):
            return True

    def functions(self):
        # We set the initial position to it's default
        self.initial_pos = 220

        # checkSelection(posX, startPosY, endPosY)
        self.event_i = self.checkSelection(42, self.initial_pos, self.initial_pos + self.button.get_height())
        self.event_e = self.checkSelection(42, self.initial_pos + self.button.get_height()*3 + 75, self.initial_pos + self.button.get_height()*4 + 75)

        if self.event_i:
            print 'Begin'
            current_display = GameDisplay()
        if self.event_e:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
            sys.exit()

        self.event_i = self.event_g = self.event_t = self.event_e = False

    def drawButtons(self):
        # Draws the button elements from the Menu view
        self.initial_pos = 220

        window.blit(self.start_button, (42,self.initial_pos))
        window.blit(self.tutorial_button, (42,self.initial_pos + self.button.get_height() + 25))
        window.blit(self.top10_button, (42,self.initial_pos + self.button.get_height()*2 + 50))
        window.blit(self.salir_button, (42,self.initial_pos + self.button.get_height()*3 + 75))

    def drawText(self):
        # Draws the texts elements for the buttons
        self.initial_pos = 220 + 25

        # Setting Text
        self.start_text = 'Inicar Partida'
        self.tutorial_text = 'Como Jugar'
        self.top10_text = 'Top 10'
        self.salir_text = 'Salir del Juego'

        # Setting Font
        self.myfont = pygame.font.SysFont("Verdana", 19)
        self.myfont.set_bold(True)

        # Render Text
        self.start = self.myfont.render(self.start_text, 1, self.text_color)
        self.tutorial = self.myfont.render(self.tutorial_text, 1, self.text_color)
        self.top10 = self.myfont.render(self.top10_text, 1, self.text_color)
        self.salir = self.myfont.render(self.salir_text, 1, self.text_color)

        # Ajustamos la posicion XY del texto para que este en el medio del boton
        self.textPosX = (display_width/2) - (self.start.get_width()/2) - 21
        self.textPosY = self.initial_pos - 5

        window.blit(self.start, (self.textPosX,self.textPosY))

        self.textPosX = (display_width/2) - (self.tutorial.get_width()/2) - 21

        window.blit(self.tutorial, (self.textPosX, self.initial_pos + self.button.get_height() + 25 -5))

        self.textPosX = (display_width/2) - (self.top10.get_width()/2) - 21

        window.blit(self.top10, (self.textPosX, self.initial_pos + self.button.get_height()*2 + 50 -5))

        self.textPosX = (display_width/2) - (self.salir.get_width()/2) - 21

        window.blit(self.salir, (self.textPosX, self.initial_pos + self.button.get_height()*3 + 75 -5))

    def drawAll(self):
        # Executes all the draw functions
        self.drawButtons()
        self.drawText()


class GameDisplay():
    # Game view
    def __init__(self):
        print 'Hello World'
        self.button = pygame.image.load("src/trans-button.png")
        self.button = pygame.transform.scale(self.button, ((display_width/2) - 40, 65))
        self.return_button = pygame.transform.scale(self.button, (75, 20))
        self.event_r = False

    def drawButtons(self):

        self.initial_pos_y = 0
        self.initial_pos_x = display_width - 75

        window.blit(self.return_button, (initial_pos_y, initial_pos_x))

    def drawAll(self):
        # Executes all the draw functions
        self.drawButtons()

    def checkSelection(self, posX, startPosY, endPosY):
        # We get the mouse coordinates
        self.mouse_x, self.mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        # Then proceed to evaluate it position in relation with the buttons
        if(self.mouse_x >= posX and self.mouse_x <= self.button.get_width() + posX and self.mouse_y >= startPosY and self.mouse_y <= endPosY):
            return True

    def functions(self):
        # We set the initial position to it's default
        self.initial_pos_y = 0
        self.initial_pos_x = display_width - 75

        # checkSelection(posX, startPosY, endPosY)
        self.event_r = self.checkSelection(initial_pos_x, self.initial_pos_y, self.initial_pos_y - self.return_button.get_height())
```

The MainDisplay class is in charge of handling the transition between each view since I intend to add more in the future. When the app starts I create a new MainDisplay called current_display which receives the starter view as a parameter.

```
# Setting up Display
current_display = MainDisplay(MenuDisplay())
```

Which is executed is the main loop.

```
crashed = False

# Game Loop
while not crashed:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            crashed = True
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            current_display.functions()

    window.blit(background, (0,0))
    current_display.draw()
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)

#End Game
pygame.quit()
quit()
sys.exit()
```

The first view works like a charm.

And when the user click the start button it should go to the next view, the click event I handle it checking if the mouse position collides with the button position.

```
def functions(self):
    # We set the initial position to it's default
    self.initial_pos = 220

    # checkSelection(posX, startPosY, endPosY)
    self.event_i = self.checkSelection(42, self.initial_pos, self.initial_pos + self.button.get_height())
    self.event_e = self.checkSelection(42, self.initial_pos + self.button.get_height()*3 + 75, self.initial_pos + self.button.get_height()*4 + 75)

    if self.event_i:
        print 'Begin'
        current_display = GameDisplay()
    if self.event_e:
        pygame.quit()
        quit()
        sys.exit()

    self.event_i = self.event_g = self.event_t = self.event_e = False

def checkSelection(self, posX, startPosY, endPosY):
        # We get the mouse coordinates
        self.mouse_x, self.mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        # Then proceed to evaluate it position in relation with the buttons
        if(self.mouse_x >= posX and self.mouse_x <= self.button.get_width() + posX and self.mouse_y >= startPosY and self.mouse_y <= endPosY):
            return True
```

In order to make sure the event happened I added a print for debugging.
The GameDisplay __ init __ does works because the 'Hello World'message does shows, however the UI view doesn't change.

Here is the complete code:

```
import pygame
import sys
from random import randint

pygame.init()

class MainDisplay:
    # Handles current view and all it's events and acts as broker between views
    def __init__(self, view):
        self.current_view = view

    def draw(self):
        self.current_view.drawAll()

    def functions(self):
        self.current_view.functions()

class MenuDisplay:
    # Menu View
    def __init__(self):
        self.button = pygame.image.load("src/trans-button.png")
        self.button = pygame.transform.scale(self.button, (display_width - 84, 70))
        self.start_button = self.button
        self.tutorial_button = self.button
        self.top10_button = self.button
        self.salir_button = self.button
        self.initial_pos = 220
        self.event_i = self.event_g = self.event_t = self.event_e = False
        self.text_color = (255,255,0)

    def checkSelection(self, posX, startPosY, endPosY):
        # We get the mouse coordinates
        self.mouse_x, self.mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        # Then proceed to evaluate it position in relation with the buttons
        if(self.mouse_x >= posX and self.mouse_x <= self.button.get_width() + posX and self.mouse_y >= startPosY and self.mouse_y <= endPosY):
            return True

    def functions(self):
        # We set the initial position to it's default
        self.initial_pos = 220

        # checkSelection(posX, startPosY, endPosY)
        self.event_i = self.checkSelection(42, self.initial_pos, self.initial_pos + self.button.get_height())
        self.event_e = self.checkSelection(42, self.initial_pos + self.button.get_height()*3 + 75, self.initial_pos + self.button.get_height()*4 + 75)

        if self.event_i:
            print 'Begin'
            current_display = GameDisplay()
        if self.event_e:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
            sys.exit()

        self.event_i = self.event_g = self.event_t = self.event_e = False

    def drawButtons(self):
        # Draws the button elements from the Menu view
        self.initial_pos = 220

        window.blit(self.start_button, (42,self.initial_pos))
        window.blit(self.tutorial_button, (42,self.initial_pos + self.button.get_height() + 25))
        window.blit(self.top10_button, (42,self.initial_pos + self.button.get_height()*2 + 50))
        window.blit(self.salir_button, (42,self.initial_pos + self.button.get_height()*3 + 75))

    def drawText(self):
        # Draws the texts elements for the buttons
        self.initial_pos = 220 + 25

        # Setting Text
        self.start_text = 'Inicar Partida'
        self.tutorial_text = 'Como Jugar'
        self.top10_text = 'Top 10'
        self.salir_text = 'Salir del Juego'

        # Setting Font
        self.myfont = pygame.font.SysFont("Verdana", 19)
        self.myfont.set_bold(True)

        # Render Text
        self.start = self.myfont.render(self.start_text, 1, self.text_color)
        self.tutorial = self.myfont.render(self.tutorial_text, 1, self.text_color)
        self.top10 = self.myfont.render(self.top10_text, 1, self.text_color)
        self.salir = self.myfont.render(self.salir_text, 1, self.text_color)

        # Ajustamos la posicion XY del texto para que este en el medio del boton
        self.textPosX = (display_width/2) - (self.start.get_width()/2) - 21
        self.textPosY = self.initial_pos - 5

        window.blit(self.start, (self.textPosX,self.textPosY))

        self.textPosX = (display_width/2) - (self.tutorial.get_width()/2) - 21

        window.blit(self.tutorial, (self.textPosX, self.initial_pos + self.button.get_height() + 25 -5))

        self.textPosX = (display_width/2) - (self.top10.get_width()/2) - 21

        window.blit(self.top10, (self.textPosX, self.initial_pos + self.button.get_height()*2 + 50 -5))

        self.textPosX = (display_width/2) - (self.salir.get_width()/2) - 21

        window.blit(self.salir, (self.textPosX, self.initial_pos + self.button.get_height()*3 + 75 -5))

    def drawAll(self):
        # Executes all the draw functions
        self.drawButtons()
        self.drawText()


class GameDisplay():
    # Game view
    def __init__(self):
        print 'Hello World'
        self.button = pygame.image.load("src/trans-button.png")
        self.button = pygame.transform.scale(self.button, ((display_width/2) - 40, 65))
        self.return_button = pygame.transform.scale(self.button, (75, 20))
        self.event_r = False

    def drawButtons(self):

        self.initial_pos_y = 0
        self.initial_pos_x = display_width - 75

        window.blit(self.return_button, (initial_pos_y, initial_pos_x))

    def drawAll(self):
        # Executes all the draw functions
        self.drawButtons()

    def checkSelection(self, posX, startPosY, endPosY):
        # We get the mouse coordinates
        self.mouse_x, self.mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        # Then proceed to evaluate it position in relation with the buttons
        if(self.mouse_x >= posX and self.mouse_x <= self.button.get_width() + posX and self.mouse_y >= startPosY and self.mouse_y <= endPosY):
            return True

    def functions(self):
        # We set the initial position to it's default
        self.initial_pos_y = 0
        self.initial_pos_x = display_width - 75

        # checkSelection(posX, startPosY, endPosY)
        self.event_r = self.checkSelection(initial_pos_x, self.initial_pos_y, self.initial_pos_y - self.return_button.get_height())

# Display Settings
display_width = 830
display_height = 625

window = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))

pygame.display.set_caption("This is my Game")

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Background Settings
background = pygame.image.load("src/background.jpg")
background = pygame.transform.scale(background, (display_width, display_height))

# Setting up Display
current_display = MainDisplay(MenuDisplay())

crashed = False

# Game Loop
while not crashed:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            crashed = True
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            current_display.functions()

    window.blit(background, (0,0))
    current_display.draw()
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)

#End Game
pygame.quit()
quit()
sys.exit()
```

Comment: Fixed it, instead of initializing the MainDisplay class again I added a function called updateViews in which I pass the GameDisplay as a parameter.

Comment: Please answer your question as an answer, not as a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was because I was missing a )

Thanks a lot Martin.